# Routing Extjs deeper navigation

Tags: extjs, routes, extjs6

I'm writing a Extjs app in the 6.2.0 version, I’ve got a routing situation.
My problem is when we enter on the NavigateDeep if I enter the Url ok it catches but it doesn’t render.
I define the routes on the main Controller like:

```
Ext.define('App.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',
    listen : {
        controller : {
            '*' : {
                unmatchedroute : 'onRouteChange1',
                changeroute: 'changeRoute'
            }
        }
    },

    routes: {
        ':node': 'onNavigate',
        ':node/:id' : 'onNavigateDeep',
        ':node/:id/:tabid' : 'onNavigateDeepTab'
    },

    lastView: null,
    onRouteChange1: function(){
        console.log("hier unmatched route");
    },
    setCurrentView: function(hashTag) {
        hashTag = (hashTag || '').toLowerCase();
        console.log("hash:" + hashTag);
        var me = this,
            refs = me.getReferences(),
            mainCard = refs.mainCardPanel,
            mainLayout = mainCard.getLayout(),
            navigationList = refs.navigationTreeList,
            store = navigationList.getStore(),
            node = store.findNode('routeId', hashTag) ||
                store.findNode('viewType', hashTag),
            view = (node && node.get('viewType')) || 'page404',
            lastView = me.lastView,
            existingItem = mainCard.child('component[routeId=' + hashTag + ']'),
            newView;

        // Kill any previously routed window
        if (lastView && lastView.isWindow) {
            lastView.destroy();
        }
        lastView = mainLayout.getActiveItem();

        if (!existingItem) {
            newView = Ext.create({
                xtype: view,
                routeId: hashTag,  // for existingItem search later
                hideMode: 'offsets'
            });
        }

        if (!newView || !newView.isWindow) {
            // !newView means we have an existing view, but if the newView isWindow
            // we don't add it to the card layout.
            if (existingItem) {
                // We don't have a newView, so activate the existing view.
                if (existingItem !== lastView) {
                    mainLayout.setActiveItem(existingItem);
                }
                newView = existingItem;
            }
            else {
                // newView is set (did not exist already), so add it and make it the
                // activeItem.
                Ext.suspendLayouts();
                mainLayout.setActiveItem(mainCard.add(newView));
                Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
            }
        }

        navigationList.setSelection(node);

        if (newView.isFocusable(true)) {
            newView.focus();
        }

        me.lastView = newView;
    },

    onNavigationTreeSelectionChange: function (tree, node) {
        var to = node && (node.get('routeId') || node.get('viewType'));

        if (to) {
            console.log("to;:" + to);
            this.redirectTo(to);
        }
    },

    onToggleNavigationSize: function () {
        var me = this,
            refs = me.getReferences(),
            navigationList = refs.navigationTreeList,
            wrapContainer = refs.mainContainerWrap,
            collapsing = !navigationList.getMicro(),
            new_width = collapsing ? 64 : 250;

        if (Ext.isIE9m || !Ext.os.is.Desktop) {
            Ext.suspendLayouts();

            refs.logo.setWidth(new_width);

            navigationList.setWidth(new_width);
            navigationList.setMicro(collapsing);

            Ext.resumeLayouts(); // do not flush the layout here...

            // No animation for IE9 or lower...
            wrapContainer.layout.animatePolicy = wrapContainer.layout.animate = null;
            wrapContainer.updateLayout();  // ... since this will flush them
        }
        else {
            if (!collapsing) {
                // If we are leaving micro mode (expanding), we do that first so that the
                // text of the items in the navlist will be revealed by the animation.
                navigationList.setMicro(false);
            }

            // Start this layout first since it does not require a layout
            refs.logo.animate({dynamic: true, to: {width: new_width}});

            // Directly adjust the width config and then run the main wrap container layout
            // as the root layout (it and its chidren). This will cause the adjusted size to
            // be flushed to the element and animate to that new size.
            navigationList.width = new_width;
            wrapContainer.updateLayout({isRoot: true});
            navigationList.el.addCls('nav-tree-animating');

            // We need to switch to micro mode on the navlist *after* the animation (this
            // allows the "sweep" to leave the item text in place until it is no longer
            // visible.
            if (collapsing) {
                navigationList.on({
                    afterlayoutanimation: function () {
                        navigationList.setMicro(true);
                        navigationList.el.removeCls('nav-tree-animating');
                    },
                    single: true
                });
            }
        }
    },

    onMainViewRender:function() {
        if (!window.location.hash) {
            this.redirectTo("dashboard");
        }
    },
    changeRoute: function(controller,route){
        this.redirectTo(route,true);
        console.log("change route fired");
    },
    onClickLogoutButton: function () {
        // Remove the localStorage key/value
        localStorage.removeItem('LoggedIn');

        // Remove Main View
        this.getView().destroy();

        // Add the Login Window
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'login'
        });
    },
    onClickShareButton: function(){
        var text = window.location;
        window.prompt("Copy to clipboard:", text);
    },


    onNavigate:function(node){
        console.log("on route change");
        this.setCurrentView(node);
    },
    onNavigateDeep: function (node, id) {
        console.log("Tab");
        console.log(node + '/' + id);
        var route = node+'/'+id;
        this.setCurrentView(route);

    },
    onNavigateDeepTab: function (node, id, tabid) {
        console.log("navigate Tab");

    }

});
```

My main view is:

```
Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'App.view.Dashboard',
        'App.view.immo.List',
        'App.view.settings.Settings',
        'App.view.news.News',
        'App.view.help.Help'
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',

    cls: 'sencha-dash-viewport',
    itemId: 'mainView',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    listeners: {
        render: 'onMainViewRender'
    },

    items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            cls: 'dash-dash-headerbar shadow',
            height: 64,
            itemId: 'headerBar',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                reference: 'logo',
                cls: 'logo',
                html: '<div class="main-logo"><img src="resources/images/logo.png">App</div>',
                width: 250
            }, {
                margin: '0 0 0 8',
                ui: 'header',
                iconCls:'x-fa fa-navicon',
                id: 'main-navigation-btn',
                handler: 'onToggleNavigationSize',
                tooltip: 'Navigation umschalten'
            },
            '->',
             {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 ui: 'header',
                 iconCls: 'x-fa fa-share-alt',
                 handler: 'onClickShareButton',
                 tooltip: 'Share'
             },
            {
                iconCls:'x-fa fa-question',
                ui: 'header',
                href: '#help',
                hrefTarget: '_self',
                tooltip: 'Hilfe'
            }, {
                iconCls:'x-fa fa-th-large',
                ui: 'header',
                href: '#Dashboard',
                hrefTarget: '_self',
                tooltip: 'Zum Dashboard'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'header',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-power-off',
                handler: 'onClickLogoutButton',
                tooltip: 'Logout'
            }]
    }, {
            xtype: 'maincontainerwrap',
            id: 'main-view-detail-wrap',
            reference: 'mainContainerWrap',
            flex: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'treelist',
                reference: 'navigationTreeList',
                itemId: 'navigationTreeList',
                ui: 'navigation',
                store: 'NavigationTree',
                width: 250,
                expanderFirst: false,
                expanderOnly: false,
                listeners: {
                    selectionchange: 'onNavigationTreeSelectionChange'
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                reference: 'mainCardPanel',
                cls: 'sencha-dash-right-main-container',
                itemId: 'contentPanel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'card',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }
            }]
        }]
});
```

When we click on the tree I change the container but one of them has the route if the :id where I have a Tab:

```
Ext.define('App.view.settings.Settings',{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'settings',
    itemId:'settings',
    requires: [
        'App.view.settings.SettingsController',
        'App.view.settings.SettingsModel',
        'App.view.settings.property.Property',
        'App.view.settings.user.User'
    ],

    controller: 'settings-settings',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'settings-settings'
    },
    reference: 'tab',
    tabPosition: 'left',

    tabBar:{
        flex: 1,
        tabRotation: 0,
        tabStretchMax: true,
        cls: 'immoNavi'
    },
    layout: 'Container',

    defaults: {
        padding: 0,
        textAlign: 'left'
    },
    listeners: {
        tabchange: 'onTabChange'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        tabConfig:{
            hidden: true
        }
    },{
        title: 'Property',
        itemId: 'property',
        xtype: 'property',
        cls: 'container'
    },{
        title: 'User',
        itemId: 'user',
        xtype: 'user'
    }]
});
```

I went through the documentation but didn't find any tip that might help me with it. What am I missing here?  Should I take care the rendering on the tab controller? Or How? 
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reproduce this at https://fiddle.sencha.com ? Since it's a somewhat complex problem, it would be much easier for others to investigate.

Comment: Hey @JohnKrull thanks for the reply, I put everything there: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r82
I'm a little bit noobie on sencha, i'm using MVVM pattern on fiddle couldn't put everything working but it's there all the code that i'm using. I manage to link the Tree with the routing : localhost/#settings on both ways, with the event on the tab and if we insert the link and press enter, my problem is when we go deep like: localhost/#settings/user that I have no idea how to render it. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Does the fiddle preview load for you? It is not working for me.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Fiddle isn't working